# Backbone.Collection.reset() => child view is out of sync with parent

Tags: backbone.js, single-page-application, backbone.paginator

I have a list of items. They are stored in backbone pageable collection.

They are displayed like this

|---item1---------------------------|
|---item2---------------------------|
|---item3---------------------------|
|---item4---------------------------|
|---item5---------------------------|
|---item6---------------------------|
|---item7---------------------------|
           << 1,2,3...end >>

User can click on individual item to open detail view in a separate page. Detail view has listeners initialized 
when it's created. Those listeners are bound to the item model.

Since the detail view is **huge**, I cache it in the DOM by toggling the visibility. 
The subsequent click on the item will toggle the cached view.

------ here is the problem -----

When item list is switched to another page, the collection is reset (by paginator). And all the models previously stored in the collection is dereferenced and 
a new set of models is created. So after the page is switched back and forth, the previously opened item has a different copy of itself stored 
in the collection. So when I change the name of the item in the detail view (in the view cache), the name in the item list is not changed.

The views are out of sync! because they are referencing to different models.

Not sure if anyone else encounter this before. If you do, please share with me how you solve it.

Thanks very much.

Comment: From the API docs it looks there are three mode: `server`, `client` and `infinite`.  The first one holds only one page in memory and resets every time but the other two seem to cache it.  I wonder if that's the issue?  If not, you might look at line 882 for the conditions under which reset happens and possibly modify that for your app.

Comment: @coderek Some code to illustrate your problem would really help to understand your meaning and would give a basis to work with

Comment: I'd start by looking at the `fullCollection` attribute of the collection. But without some more concrete code, it's difficult to give you a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straight-forward way to maintain a fresh reference between your list view items and the corresponding detail view, on page change, is to re-render the detail view. But I'm assuming this options *is not* acceptable within the scope of your project.

What I often do, when I have the task of forming relationships within logically separate views is use listeners. As long as the views share a unique identifier (for example, they both share a model, or at least identical model ids), I can always send a message that will reach the view I'm interested in.

For this you'll need a centralized event hub, which with Backbone is trivially easy to generate. In some appropiately global variable (like, for example, `MyApp`) we simply do:

```
MyApp.EventBus = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);
```

### Set up the detail view

On the detail view initialize function I would drop this listener,

```
initialize: function () {
  // Listen to a toggle visibility on this view
  this.listenTo(MyApp.EventBus, 'detail-view:toggle-view', toggleView);
},

toggleView: function (id) {
  if (this.model.id == id) {
     // Show this view if I have the passed id
     this.$el.show()
     // Notify the parent list item view that its detail view exists
     MyApp.EventBus.trigger('detail:view:exists', true);
  } else {
    // Hide all other views
    this.$el.hide();
  }
},

changeName: function () {
  // logic that parses DOM user input to 
  // local variable name

  // We now trigger an event 'detail-view:change:name', and we send as 
  // parameters our model's id and the new name
  MyApp.EventBus.trigger('detail-view:change:name', this.model.id, name);
}
```

### Setting up the list item view

The list item view will want to listen to a name change (or any other model property in the detail view that you want the list item to be aware of). So we'll set up a handler for the 'detail-view:change:name' event.

We'll also want to wire our click handler to toggle the visibility of the list item's detail view. The tricky part is to handle the event that a view has not been rendered yet (I'm assuming you're lazy loading the detail view). So we set up a second listener for the `detail:view:exists` event the detail view triggers when it catches a `detail-view:toggle-view` event. If we don't hear the `detail:view:exists` event from the targeted detail view in a timely manner (I'm using 100 ms, but you can play around with that to suit your needs), then we render the view.

```
initialize: function () {
  // Listen to when the detail associated with this list item changes
  // the the list item name
  this.listenTo(MyApp.EventBus, 'detail-view:change:name', onNameChange);
  // Set a property in this view if its detail view exists
  this.listenTo(MyApp.EventBus, 'detail:view:exists', 
    _.bind(function () { this.detailViewExists = true; }, this));
  // Create a debounced function that tests whether this view's
  // detail view exists
  _.debounce(_.bind(this.handleViewState, this), 100);
},

events {
  click: 'toggleDetailView'
},

toggleDetailView: function (id) {
  MyApp.EventBus.trigger('detail-view:toggle-view', this.model.id);
  this.handleViewState();
},

// Debounced function that will wait 100ms asynchronously for the 
// detail view to respond. If the detailViewExists bit is not set to true 
// then we assume the view does not exist and we render it
handleViewState: function () {
  if (!this.detailViewExists) 
     // The view does not exist, render and attach the view

  // Set the bit to false to allow testing in the event that the detail view
  // is destroyed in the future
  this.detailViewExists = false;
},

changeName: function (id, newname) {
  if (this.model.id == id) {
     // Change the name of this list item view
     this.$('.item-name').text(newname);
}
```

### The take-away

Now, the reference between these two disparate views is the shared unique identifier. Since, by design, these two identifiers are unique in their scope, and should not change, and assuming the detail view has been rendered and attached to the DOM, then regardless of the rendering its state the list item view will always be able to communicate with its detail view.

Comment: This is a pretty neat solution. The tradeoff is that, we got to setup a separate event system for model-view binding. (I am already using Backbone.Radio for event bus, but I've never thought of putting it in the middle of views and models). Since the list-item view is not complex, there shouldn't be too much burden. Thanks.

Comment: The good news is that you can use Backbone.Radio seamlessly with this solution (that's what I use!). Just swap out the `EventBus` for a ` Backbone.Radio.vent`, or better, make your own channel for the solution.

Comment: BTW, you'll notice they're no actual model-view event binding. *That* would've been ideal, and simplify the code tremendously. But, if you can guarantee that on a page-change the collection is feed the identical model instances that where used before, then view-model binding would work. I can provide you with that solution, also. In the Answer above, we're just exploiting the fact that both views share a unique identifier, in this case the `model.id`.

Comment: I mean, logically I need to have a separate mechanism. But sure, Backbone.Radio can be used to implement that.